# Android || Get Current Google Maps Route Information

Tags: android, google-maps

Imagine a scenario where a user selects a route in the Google Maps app. They then begin following that route.

Is there a Google Maps API functionality that would allow you to get the current route information? e.g. Route Start Point, Route Finish Point, ETA, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: No.

Long Answer:

There isn't an official "API" per se, but there *are* ways to do it.  [Here](http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/#svn/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx/src/org/ci/geo/route/android) is a Google code project, and [here](http://csie-tw.blogspot.in/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html) is a supposedly working example but the English is hard to understand.

You could always use their web API as opposed to the Android/Java API, it's known to have better flexibility when it comes to traffic, driving directions, and other features.  The downside of this is that you'd have to embed it into a `WebView` or similar web interface.

Also, there are places to generate driving directions into KML files.  [Here](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-part-1-get-the-route/) is a great blogpost series about getting directions from OpenStreetMap, and [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) is the official OpenStreetMap wiki.  That should be enough to get you started; you can also find more sites on Google than I could possibly link here.

Good luck!

Comment: Any newer answers to this?